# Can Yodlee be used securely without IB credentials going through my servers

Tags: security, yodlee

Hi I'm working with yodlee API to scrape data from customers bank accounts.
For this, Yodlee needs customers Internet Banking Credentials. The examples I've seen request the user's credentials, pass them through your own server to Yodlee. Ideally I would like the user to authenticate with Yodlee and never give myself access to their credentials. This is what I'm thinking of:

1) **My server** creates a new cobrand session with yodlee using cobrandLogin and cobrandPassword

2) **cobSessionToken** is sent to the users browser

3) user logs in passing their IB username and password and the cobSessionToken to yodlee.

Is this setup secure? Is there any risk in exposing CobSessionToken to clients?

Answer (score 1):

This setup is highly secure. However we recommend you to not to expose the cobsession token to the user, instead make the users to use your cobrand context in the backend and generate their user context.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Krithik

Comment: Thanks I'll look into setting up a user context, can this be done in a way that doesn't require users to send their credentials through my server?

Comment: Since your Ip while be whitelisted to interact with Yodlee. So the user request will be reaching yodlee via your server.